# Deploying in 1.24 version Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks

As you already know , Kubernetes in version 1.24 is moving on from DockerShim.

I will need your help here because all of our deployments in Jenkins are running through a Docker Pod agent via Kubernetes plugin from Jenkins.

I will give you an example of part from our pipelines in Jenkins:

```
agent {
    kubernetes {
      // label 'test'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
labels:
  component: ci
spec:
  # Use service account that can deploy to all namespaces
  serviceAccountName: jenkins
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:latest
    #image: debian:buster
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: docker-sock
  volumes:
    - name: docker-sock
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
"""
```

And then basically in this stage we build our image :

```
stage('Create & Tag Image') {
      steps {
        container('docker') {
          sh '''
             aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  < AWS ECR URL >
  
             docker build --build-arg -t < AWS ECR URL > --network=host .
          '''
        }
      }
```

The result is the error that **doesn't listen to the docker socket** as i mention in version 1.24 Kubernetes doesnt support docker daemon anymore.

I would like to ask you how you deploy now in Kubernetes 1.24.

I read that there are some tools **[img](https://github.com/genuinetools/img), [buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah), [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko), or [buildkit-cli-for-kubectl](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/buildkit-cli-for-kubectl)** that don’t require Docker.

Can you recommend me any solution or help in this subject ?

We are using EKS from AWS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mirantis [cri-dockerd](https://github.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd), some explanations can be found [here](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-install-cri-dockerd-and-migrate-nodes-from-dockershim/).